# What is this object outside the ISS that looks like a loudspeaker?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object

Things in space are not always what they seem. The question [Why does there appear to be a 180-degree stereo microphone array outside the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18529/12102) makes that clear.

What is this object shown to the right of astronaut Michael Foale in the BBC article [The Astronaut Fighting to Save our Home in Space](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20180105-the-astronaut-fighting-to-save-our-home-in-space)?

> Michael Foale has spent more than a year in space on various missions (Credit: Nasa)

[image]

Comment: It's a loudsp.... uh, no.

Comment: It's a loudspeaker that emits the sound from the 180-degree stereo microphone!

Comment: @OrganicMarble apparently it's this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/aonjC.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a light, or a luminaire if you're from Quebec.

The lights are part of the ETVCG (**E**xternal **T**ele**v**ision **C**amera **G**roup).

[image]

The picture is from a presentation on the new high-def cameras, which can be found [here](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/V_Studer-External_High_Definition_Camera.pdf).

The light pans and tilts with the cameras, as seen in this picture from the same presentation.
[image]

You can see an ETVCG at the right of this picture from the STS-127 mission. It's watching the on-going robotic ops, probably the clearance between the shuttle arm and the Japanese module.

[image]

And here's a cropped version of that. You can see that the light appears to be on.

[image]

Comment: "Figure 6 - Various Pan and Tilt Configurations" looks like one [Drill-O-Matic](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/images/thumb/f/f5/%27Drill-O-Matic%27_Mining_Excavator_%28dep_comp%29.png/200px-%27Drill-O-Matic%27_Mining_Excavator_%28dep_comp%29.png)