# Zebulon Scoville "looked up at the video monitors and saw all the ice and thruster firings." Exactly what ice did Scoville see? Why ice? Where?

Tags: iss, nasa, photography, video, ice

Gizmodo's [The ISS Backflipped Out of Control After Russian Module Misfired, New Details Reveal](https://gizmodo.com/the-iss-backflipped-out-of-control-after-russian-module-1847415359/amp) quotes Zebulon Scoville, the NASA flight director in charge at the time:

> “And so at first I was like, ‘Oh, is this a false indication?’” Mr. Scoville said. “**And then I looked up at the video monitors and saw all the ice and thruster firings.** This is no kidding. A real event. So let’s get to it. You get about half a breath of ‘Oh, geez, what now?’ and then you kind of push that down and just work the problem.”
>
> **Nauka’s thrusters had started firing, trying to pull away from a space station it was securely docked to.**
>
> Worse, there was no way to turn them off.
>
> His counterparts at the mission control in Russia told him that Nauka was configured so that it could receive commands directly only from a ground station in Russia. The next pass over Russia was 70 minutes away.

**Question:** Which monitors might Scoville be referring to? Exactly what ice did Scoville see? Why was there ice? Where was the ice?

Comment: I think its the same shots we see here in the little monitors, and bumps up to the other view most often shown at 0.46. https://youtu.be/NJ8qsWXgjcc?t=35 I think all the particles moving around are something you should not see if you are not carrying out a planned maneuver. I read the thrusters were seen (but not seen a video per se) - and it was not a constant thrust, but rather constant, consistent pulses as you normally see with RCS maneuvers. Except this was obviously not the time to be seeing them at all, and they did not stop.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby oh, that's the "[stereo microphones](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18529/12102)"

Comment: The monitors in the MCC.

Comment: ha, i was so used to seeing the MCC that I didn't think people might not know where these 'monitors', that are most often referred to, are placed. To clarify that video i linked to was some guy streaming/recording and unconnected to NASA afaik.

Comment: think this is around the time of the incident (on the go so cant check) https://youtu.be/DzDoPbQVPfE ; and reverse view: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CCW7PGGg7DI/maxresdefault.jpg , showing some monitors